# Acumatica Rest API Endpoint mapping unbound fields or fields that are not on the screen

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to map fields that are not on the screen using the Contract Based API? In the SOAP API you could assign a value to a field not on the screen by using the Object and Field Names. I don't see any way to do this in the Contract Based API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map fields that are not on the screen in a web service endpoint, you should manually type DAC field name in the Mapped Field column. For an example, check how LastModifiedDateTime was mapped for the SalesOrder entity inside the Default endpoint:
[image]

Comment: I hate hi-jacking this thread, but can you point me to where I can find Acumatica Rest API Endpoint Documentation "Does it even exist?"  I've reached the end of the internet looking and I just feel dark and I'm hoping you can help!

Comment: Have you checked **Integration Development Guide** -> **Working with the Contract-Based REST API** at https://help.acumatica.com/